# Redirecting HTTP requests to 2 different servers

Tags: apache, tomcat, networking

The problem is quite simple : I have 2 web servers on my LAN, with 2 different application stacks. One runs on Tomcat, the other on Apache. I also have a public IP and a domain name. I'd like to be able to access one server or the other from outside, using port 80, for example through app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com.

I read about mod_jk, but I can't install anything on the existing Apache server. Should I put another Apache server in front of the others ?

Is there any chance of being able to route requests correctly if I had 2 public IPs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read about mod_jk, but I can't install anything on the existing Apache server. Should I put another Apache server in front of the others ?

Yes. If you can't change anything on the existing Apache, then it would be best to add another Apache in front of the two web servers. You can set up a `<VirtualHost>` for each sub-domain. And use mod_jk in one to forward to tomcat and [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) in the other to forward to the existing Apache.

> Is there any chance of being able to route requests correctly if I had
>   2 public IPs ?

Yes. Your router or firewall should be able to forward each external IP address to the particular internal IP address of each web server. That way you don't need another Apache. Public IP addresses are expensive however. One day you might need a third or fourth web server. What then? It doesn't hurt to invest some time in how to set up a front-end Apache.